# making getopt() process argv[0]

Tags: c, getopt

I trying to emulate `main()` function like behavior for normal functions using string tokenizing and storing tokens in a NULL terminated `char*` array.

Every thing is fine except `getopt()`. It won't rearrange `argv[0]` coz it expects the first argument to be program name. But for my function the `argv[0]` isn't the program name. I want to make `getopt()` to also rearrange `argv[0]`(non-option). How do I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is a misuse of `getopt()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
c = getopt(argc + 1, argv - 1, "xyz")
```

Edit: Which, as pointed out below, is a hack But I'd be interested to see a machine on which it didn't work.

Comment: I tend to say that `argv - 1`provokes undefined behaviour. So I' d consider this solution a dirty and unportable hack.

Comment: only if you access it. I doubt that getopt does,

Comment: @TomTanner Technically I believe you're wrong. The standard says that a pointer addition or subtraction which gives a result outside the array bounds is undefined behaviour even if you subsequently do nothing with it, except for the special case of one past the end.  

In practise it's likely to work most places, but by the letter of the standard it's UB.

Comment: @TomTanner: I doubt this. Please have look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18186987/694576

Answer (score 3):

`getopt(3)` uses a global variable `optind` (option index) to track its progress through `argv` and initializes it to 1. Try setting `optind = 0` before reading the options.

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that. I've set optind = 0 before the first call to getopt(). Doesn't work.

Comment: And what were the results?

Comment: Result is same even after setting optind = 0. argv[0] element is at the same place

Comment: What values is it returning while you call it?

Answer (score 0):

Though the hack @Tom Tanner suggested worked for certain systems, it didn't compile for the target which I'm supposed to make it work. Another work around I found is to replace the first argument in my argv[] array with a dummy string and use getopt() with it.