# Is GCC's option -O2 breaking this small program or do I have undefined behavior

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, inline-functions

I found this problem in a very large application, have made an SSCCE from it. I don't know whether the code has undefined behavior or `-O2` breaks it.

When compiling it with `gcc a.c -o a.exe -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror` it prints **5**.

But it prints **25** when compiling without `-O2` (eg `-O1`) or uncommenting one of the 2 commented lines (prevent inlining).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// __attribute__((noinline)) 
int f(int* todos, int input) {
    int* cur = todos-1; // fixes the ++ at the beginning of the loop
    int result = input;
    while(1) {
        cur++;
        int ch = *cur;
        // printf("(%i)\n", ch);
        switch(ch) {
            case 0:;
                goto end;
            case 1:;
                result = result*result;
            break;
        }
    }
    end:
    return result;
}
int main() {
    int todos[] = { 1, 0}; // 1:square, 0:end
    int input = 5;
    int result = f(todos, input);
    printf("=%i\n", result);
    printf("end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Is GCC's option `-O2` breaking this small program or do I have undefined behavior somewhere?

Comment: UB or not, I would recommend getting rid of `todos - 1` and using `int ch = *cur++;` instead of incrementing before dereference.

Comment: According to GDB, when compiled with -O2, todos has the value {-5632, 0} ... but I can't understand why!

Comment: Valgrind warns about `ch` being uninitialized.. can't understand why

Comment: the output is not 'just' =5, it's =$input !

Comment: @ChrisStratton You seem to be on to something here. When I make `todo` as `{ -1, 1, 0 }` and then pass `&todos[1]` to `f()` the program yields the desired result

Comment: I don't have gcc but the code looks fine to me. Have a look at the assembly output, try to put some printfs and try GDB although latter might be difficult with optimisations.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure I should have voted to close it as a duplicate even if it may technically qualify... I think the fact there there is a formal issue is evidenced at the other question, but none of the answers are wonderfully satisfying.

Comment: so it is because of the `todos-1` even though it does not derefenrence? **interesting!**

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes. accepted ouah's answer which was quoting the *reason*.

Comment: Which version of gcc do you use on what platform ?

Comment: If you find the ANSI C Standard, this is explained with more verbosity, but, yes, you are invoking UB.  From the ISO Standard appendix on UB:  "Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an integer type produces a result that does not point into, or just beyond, the same array object (6.5.6)."  Keep in mind (N.B.) that 6.5.6 redefines non-array objects as single-element arrays.  Truly, the ISO standard is terrible compared to its ANSI predecessor.  Anyway, it is only recently that versions of GCC have become so draconian about UB as to break so much C code.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt +1 on that. A more common one is strict aliasing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int* cur = todos-1;
```

invokes undefined behavior. `todos - 1` is an invalid pointer address.

Emphasis mine:

> (C99, 6.5.6p8) "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of        the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**"

Comment: even though it gets incremented again before the derefenrence? **interesting!**

Comment: @eznme you don't have to dereference it to invoke undefined behavior, C says the addition of the pointer and the integer here invokes the undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, it's clearly UB. On the other hand, it is also stupid behaviour of GCC to optimize away part of that `todos[]` array because of that before-the-beginning pointer ref, **without warning the user**.

Answer (score 4):

In supplement to @ouah's answer, this explains what the compiler is doing.

Generated assembler for reference:

```
  400450:       48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  400454:       be 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%esi
  400459:       48 8d 44 24 fc          lea    -0x4(%rsp),%rax
  40045e:       c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%rsp)
  400465:       00 
  400466:       48 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%rax
  40046a:       8b 10                   mov    (%rax),%edx
```

However if I add a `printf` in `main()`:

```
  400450:       48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  400454:       bf 84 06 40 00          mov    $0x400684,%edi
  400459:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40045b:       48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  40045e:       c7 04 24 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,(%rsp)
  400465:       c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%rsp)
  40046c:       00 
  40046d:       e8 ae ff ff ff          callq  400420 <printf@plt>
  400472:       48 8d 44 24 fc          lea    -0x4(%rsp),%rax
  400477:       be 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%esi
  40047c:       48 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%rax
  400480:       8b 10                   mov    (%rax),%edx
```

Specifically (in the `printf` version), these two instructions populate the `todo` array

```
  40045e:       c7 04 24 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,(%rsp)
  400465:       c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%rsp)
```

This is conspicuously missing from the non-`printf` version, which for some reason only assigns the *second* element:

```
  40045e:       c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%rsp)
```

Comment: -1. This does not answer the question in a meaningful way. Except, of course, for people who can read assembly without problems.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar it is in addition ouah's answer, so it is fine to not repeat that only add what that answer didn't say. +1

Comment: It sounds like what this is demonstrating, is that the issue isn't really that the pointer is being functionally broken at runtime, but rather that **the optimizing compiler is deciding that the first array element is never used (in a way that complies with the rules) and thus need not ever be initialized.**  Declaring the array volatile might be another experiment to try.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That is very intersting. Since I dont want to add an answer to my own question maybe you would like to investigate that and write an answer?

Comment: I have no idea what this asm means

Comment: `%rsp` is the stack pointer. The `todo` array resides at `(%rsp)` or `0x0(%rsp)` or the beginning of the stack. `todo[1]` is four bytes into the stack, or `0x4(%rsp)`. The first example shows assignment of `$0x0` (`1`) to only `0x4(rsp)` => `todo[1] = 0`, while the second example assignments to both `$0x1` to `(%rsp)` (`todo[0]=1`) _and_ `0x0` to `0x4(%rsp)` (`todo[1]=0`)