# Will this result in a seg fault

Tags: c

Below is my code :

```
p = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
p1 = p; // p1 is float*
p--; // Will this result in a seg-fault?
```

I am guessing yes because I am trying to access memory outside allocated space.
Please could somebody confirm?

**Edit**
After seeing hobbs' answer I could not resist asking this too.

I strongly believe this will not result in a seg fault

```
printf("%f",p[n]); // because n is legally allocated for p
```

Comment: Related to and maybe duplicate of [Decrementing a pointer out of bounds; incrementing it into bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18186987/1708801) and [Does applying post-decrement on a pointer already addressing the base of an array invoke undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30512669/1708801)

Comment: Instead of guessing why don't you try it?

Comment: @JAL You can't "try" undefined behaviour

Comment: @JAL by definition *try it out* when it comes to undefined behavior does not tell you much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not accessing any memory at all; you're doing pointer arithmetic. Using pointer arithmetic to obtain a pointer that isn't inside an object or one past the end of an array is undefined behavior, so anything could happen, including a segfault. However, on most reasonable systems, *nothing* will happen unless you try to do so something with `*p`. At that point, anything could happen, from receiving garbage values, to a crash/segfault, to global thermonuclear war.

Comment: Thankyou hobbs :-).I am not going to dereference **p** for sure. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

It will result in undefined behavior. If you try to do anything with `p` by de-referencing it, the program will either throw a segmentation fault or do something else you don't want.

Comment: Why would it be UB? It is just a pointer decrement, without any attempt to dereference it.

Comment: 'int *p;' in a function would therefore be UB, even if it was malloced in the next line.

Comment: @EugeneSh. see first comment of the question by ShafikYaghmour

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, it is UB. That's why libraries that know what they are doing and need to hold pointers to another device's memory hold it as `unsigned long`  and not as pointers.

Comment: @bolov - does that not make dereferencing it somewhat difficult?

Comment: @hobbs So how is that used like everywhere in memory mapped register definitions (embedded mostly)?

Comment: ^^ there my be timer or I/O controller registers at that address

Comment: Its seems that all my embedded firmware has galloping UB:(

Comment: Also drivers on more complex, desktop OS:(

Comment: It's the second time my world of embedded firmware is about to crash. The first one was [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262801/what-is-my-best-approach-to-determining-compiler-behaviour-for-empty-infinite-lo)

Comment: @EugeneSh well 2 reasons: 1 they don't know what they are doing and it just happens that the compiler implementation doesn't result in any negative effect. 2 they know what they are doing and the compiler used guarantees that althought the standard says it is UB, it (the compiler) guarantees that in it's implementation it is well defined and ok

Comment: @hobbs I thinks it is more like they implement data pointers with unsigned integers (required size) and this has no negative effect if you create a value that is not a valid value of a pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. using pointer arithmetic to obtain a pointer other than inside an object or one past the end of an array is UB. Converting pointer<->integer is merely implementation-defined, not UB.

Comment: Can you guys please take this to a private discussion? I'm tired of getting notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You don't always encounter a seg fault when accessing memory outside the allocated area. The memory accessed may be allocated, just to something else. So either case could happen, but both are undesirable behavior.

The pointer p is allowed to contain a "bad" pointer and no undesirable behavior will occur. Consider its state when it is uninitialized. If you use the pointer by dereferencing it, then you will either encounter a seg fault or access someone else's memory, and that is undesirable behavior.

Comment: I guess the OP's point is that no such access is being performed.  A pointer is decremented, that's it.  No dereference takes place.

Comment: That's true. @sjsam, the pointer p is allowed to contain a "bad" pointer and no undesirable behavior will occur. If you use the pointer by dereferencing it, then you will either encounter a seg fault or access someone else's memory, and that is undesirable behavior.

Comment: @MartinJames: You're right, I am sure I won't dereference p. :-)